# A synonym for 'product' as below

Tags: word-request, synonyms

> A **product** of the Swansea City youth team, he has two caps for Wales and is the current record caps holder for the Wales Under 21 team with 25 caps.

<sup>([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaun_MacDonald))</sup>

I am asking because I find weird to call someone as 'product'.

Comment: Are you asking for a replacement word, or an explanation of the usage in that quote?

Comment: @NathanTuggy: a replacement word

Comment: Is he still in the Swansea City youth team?

Comment: It is a very common usage.  *A product of the New York City public schools.* or *A product of Eton and King's College, Cambridge*.

Answer (score 1):

Product here is used to mean that his development as a footballer **came from** the Swansea City Football Club youth system.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty common to refer to a person as a "product" of some formative experience, and it does not carry an inherently negative sense, apart from the implications that are being made. Saying "he's a product of a difficult childhood" or "a product of the best private education" carry obvious implications.

This locution does stress the benefit gained from the experience, over the person's inherent or pre-existing talent. To say that Patrick Stewart is the product of a Star Trek series would probably be insulting if not laughable; to say he's the product of an extensive stage drama career would likely be accurate, and acceptable. A reference to minor-league sports success, or an educational experience, is probably fine.

If very formal occasions, where great deference to the subject is being made, I'd avoid it in favour of "he benefited from", "he is an alumnus of", "he was a key member of", etc.